# Erro ao conectar oracle

Tags: oracle, php-7.1, laravel-5.6

Estou tentando realizar de insert operação no oracle pelo Laravel (5.6), mas está dando erro:

O método que faço o insert é esse:

```
public function salvar( Request $request ){
        $agenda = new Agenda();
        $agenda->dt_agenda = $request->input('data');
        $agenda->hr_agenda = $request->input('hora');
        $agenda->nm_pessoa = $request->input('nome');
        $agenda->save();
        $data = date('d/m/Y');
        return view('escala')->with( 'data', $data );
    }
```

No arquivo config/database.php está assim:

```
 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'oracle'),
    ...
    'oracle' => [
                'driver'         => 'oracle',
                'host'           => env('DB_HOST', ''),
                'port'           => env('DB_PORT', '1521'),
                'database'       => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
                'username'       => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
                'password'       => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
                'charset'        => env('DB_CHARSET', 'AL32UTF8'),
                'prefix'         => ''
            ],
```

O arquivo .env está devidamente configurado

```
DB_CONNECTION=oracle
DB_HOST=ipdoservidor
DB_PORT=1521
DB_DATABASE=banco
DB_USERNAME=login
DB_PASSWORD=senha
```

O erro que está dando é :

> ErrorException (E_WARNING) Declaration of
>   Yajra\Oci8\Oci8Connection::causedByLostConnection(Exception $e) should
>   be compatible with
>   Illuminate\Database\Connection::causedByLostConnection(Throwable $e)

Meu composer.json está assim:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.4",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "yajra/laravel-oci8": "5.6.*"
    },
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você possui a última versão deste pacote?

Como a atualização do Laravel 5.6 é recente, é normal ocorrer incompatibilidades com alguns pacotes e isso é corrigido de acordo com os issues abertos no Github referente ao mesmo.

Na aba **Issues** do [Oracle DB driver for Laravel 4|5 via OCI8](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8) podemos ver algo referente ao seu problema neste [issue](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/issues/406).

Como podemos ver, o [commit #407](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/pull/407/commits/80cddbaad68a1ec84d8ed42f5893bf24c3bd7264) realizado há 8 dias atrás (14 fev. 2018) corrige o problema.

Comment: Verdade, eu alterei no arquivo json para 5.5 e funcionou.